# Gerrit trigger build on different jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

We have gerrit setup for our project. we trigger one jenkins job which compiles the code and runs unit test. It gives +1 verified if successful and -1 if not.
What I was trying to do is on the same change another job is triggered which is present in different jenkins this will run the integration test. This should also give a +1 on successful and -1 if not.

The submission should only be merged if it receives successful from both the build on both the jenkins. Is this possible if yes how ? Any help is much appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple jobs trigged by the same Gerrit change. The result will be presented like the following example:

[image]

Comment: Can it be triggered on two different jenkins. Also mandotry verified should be present from both the jenkins

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to use two different Jenkins servers? No, I think the multiple jobs must be in the same Jenkins server.